# Jenkins- Editable Email Notification Templates plugin fails to load Templates after upgrading Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

upgraded Jenkins to 2.364, also Java version to openjdk version "11.0.16", using Email Extension Template Plugin version : 1.4

After the upgrade not able to modify/add Editable Email notification Templates.

[image: error]

I tried un-installing and re-installing Email Notification Template but it does not help.
Also verified that all dependency plugins are installed.

Appreciate any help on this. TIA

Note: Able to receive Emails from the Templates I had before upgrade, its not just accessible anymore from Jenkins UI.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved in latest version of Email Extension Template Plugin 1.5

I upgraded the plugin and re-started Jenkins and this issue was resolved.

[image]